# How to broadcast a virtually hosted web server on WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I created a Debian virtual web server hosted on a Windows 7 using VirtualBox, I need it to be accessible both from the host and from whoever connect to the host through WiFi, how can I do that? I already made an adhoc network on the windows host and did a bridge connection with the Virtual WiFi Miniport on the virtual server but every time I try to access the Virtual server's IP I got a "The connection was reset"

Comment: set your vbox network connection type to `Bridged` instead of NAT or Host-only. This will make the VM appear as a workstation on your LAN. you may have to set its IP address if you want it to be statically assigned. otherwise it will pull from the LAN DHCP server.

Comment: @FrankThomas the vbox is already bridged to the Virtual WiFi Miniport, the problem is that I can't access the IP it has been assigned

Comment: does your wifi implement a feature like "client isolation"? it will prevent wifi clients from talking to each other.

Comment: I checked, apparently there's no client isolation however when I tried to ping from the host to the guest I had the error "transmit failed. general failure." if that helps

Comment: usually that message indicates an invalid IP for pinging (like an IP that starts with 0. or 169.256.x.y). what IP are you trying to ping?

Comment: the IP I'm trying to ping is 169.253.9.137 it has been assigned to the virtual machine by DHCP

Comment: are you sure that that is not 169.**254**.9.137? 169.253.9.137 is a valid public IP address, so you should not get the General Failure message (I've tested this). 169.254.x.y however is the zero-conf/AVAHI range and is different from most IP addresses, in that you can't ping against it. see more here: https://askleo.com/why_cant_i_connect_with_a_169254xx_ip_address/  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking  I would recommend you not use a 169 address for your LAN, and confirm that your VM has the same IP network that your other lan hosts have.